# Real Analysis - continuous extension function

Tags: real-analysis

Let f : Q → R be a uniformly continuous function. Show that there exists a
uniformly continuous function **f** : R → R such that f (x) = **f** (x) for all x ∈ Q. (Notation: bold **f** is the function f extended to)

Using the theorem (a function with open interval (a,b) can be uniformly continuous iff the limits *La*=lim f (x) as x->a, *Lb*=lim f (x) as x->b, exist and the extended function **f**, with closed interval [a,b], is defined by f(x), *La*, and *Lb* ), I know how to prove uniformly continuity of functions with concrete intervals but I don't really know how to approach this question. Should I also demonstrate the limits exist and find limits using Cauchy sequence? I don't know what exactly I show do. Please help me here. Thank you!

Comment: The question of how to extend a continuous function on a dense set has been asked here a bunch, and similarly for uniformly continuous functions. If you look around, you'll find this question already asked here.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and take $\{q_n\}\subset\mathbb{Q}$ such that $\lim q_n=x$. As $\{q_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence then $\{f(q_n)\}$ is Cauchy too ($f$ is uniformly continuous), so by completeness of $\mathbb{R}$ exists $y\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim f(q_n)=y$. Define $F(x)=y$.

Comment: What is _F(x)_ = y ?

Comment: @czhang75  $F$ is the extension. If $x\notin\mathbb{Q}$ define $F(x)$ as in the answer, else, $F(x)=f(x)$